# URL redirect with urlid string creates request in a way that will never complete

Tags: php, redirect

I am stack in did!!!

I have a simple URL redirect script that I use to redirect visitor to the widget download page using again simple urlid string

```
http://www.example.com/get.php?urlid=blue_widget
```

rest is as usual, when request is send to get.php which returns the url of the download landing page.

Now the problem:

everything works fine when correct urlid is sent or if it was sent empty then my get.php redirects the visitor to my main index page. The problem happens when unknown (none existent) urlid is sent, than browser returns the following

> The page isn't redirecting properly Firefox has detected that the
>   server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will
>   never complete. This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or
>   refusing to acceptcookies.

Here is content of my get.php file

```
<?php
$urlid = $_GET['urlid']
if ($urlid == "") {$link = "http://www.example.com/";}
if ($urlid == "blue_widget") {$link = "http://www.example.com/download.php?fileid=blue_widget.doc";}
header ("Location: $link");
exit();
?>
```

Please help

Comment: $link is not set if $urlid is not blue_widget, set a default $link value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```php
<?php
if (isset($_GET['urlid'])) {
    switch ($_GET['urlid']) {
        case 'blue_widget':
            $link = 'http://www.example.com/download.php?fileid=blue_widget.doc';
            break;
        case 'second_widget':
            $link = 'http://www.example.com/download.php?fileid=second_widget.doc';
            break;
        case 'blabla':
            $link = 'http://www.example.com/download.php?fileid=blabla.doc';
            break;
        default:
            $link = 'http://www.example.com/';
    }
} else
    $link = 'http://www.example.com/';
header("Location: $link");
exit();
```

I hope it helps you! =)

Comment: THanks, this looks great, I think that this is exactly what I will use, so as I understand by going through your script is that it will not even begin looking for a $link if urlid is not set or empty. Great, one more question, I ideally would also need to set another variable such as $title for each widget and send visitor to my custom error page if urlid is empty or none existent, do I need to change the default:

Comment: Hi! There are two "error pages" in this code: the first one is the 
`default` line, when the urlid is not a widget that you are expecting! The second one is the `else` line, that happens when urlid is not set! To set another variable for each widget, just add the code to the block corresponding of the widget in the `switch` structure, between `case` and `break` statements!

Answer (score 0):

Use the PHP isset function http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php to see if $_GET['urlid'] is set.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check if the file exists by doing so :

```
if (file_exists(basename($_GET['urlid']).".doc"))
{$link = "http://www.example.com/download.php?fileid=".$_GET['urlid'].".doc";}
```

Comment: It would have been a great idea, but not all of the files are .doc files, also what if I need to redirect visitor without parsing urlid?